# How does SQL JOIN on this subquery?

Tags: sql

(FROM https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-joins-exercises.php
Example 25).

25. Write a SQL query to display the name of each company along with the ID and price for their most expensive product.

Sample table: company_mast

```
COM_ID COM_NAME
------ -------------
    11 Samsung
    12 iBall
    13 Epsion
    14 Zebronics
    15 Asus
    16 Frontech
```

Sample table: item_mast

```
 PRO_ID PRO_NAME                   PRO_PRICE    PRO_COM
------- ------------------------- ---------- ----------
    101 Mother Board                    3200         15
    102 Key Board                        450         16
    103 ZIP drive                        250         14
    104 Speaker                          550         16
    105 Monitor                         5000         11
    106 DVD drive                        900         12
    107 CD drive                         800         12
    108 Printer                         2600         13
    109 Refill cartridge                 350         13
    110 Mouse                            250         12
```

```
Sample Solution:

SELECT A.pro_name, A.pro_price, F.com_name
   FROM item_mast A INNER JOIN company_mast F
   ON A.pro_com = F.com_id
     AND A.pro_price =
     (
       SELECT MAX(A.pro_price)
         FROM item_mast A
         WHERE A.pro_com = F.com_id
     );
```

I can't figure out what is happening in the subquery and I haven't been able to find a similar use of subquery.

Comment: Don't re-use tables alias A - to make code clearer.

Comment: Also, chose table aliases that make sense, A for item_mast means nothing to me.

Comment: "Sample Solution" to what challenge? What is the desired result? Does that code achieve it? As for what happens, it gets the maximal price for each `item` per `company` and filters to that, thus isolating only the highest-price items from the outer query. There are nicer, more self-explanatory ways to do that in various RDBMSes.

Comment: Alias A used in bracket is not visible out side of it

Comment: @underscore_d The challenge is stated in the question. There is also a link to the original location of the challenge where the sample solution can be executed if one desires. The solution achieves the desired outcome but I am confused specifically about how the subquery is used as a join condition, and how WHERE is used in the subquery. To be clear, this is not my solution but one provided for educational purposes (see link provided above). I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: Further why won't 

(SELECT MAX(B.pro_price)
 FROM item_mast B
 GROUP BY B.pro_com)

work in place of the above subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Subquery may not work the way you are using. You can use inner join with the max alias.

```
SELECT A.pro_name, A2.max_price pro_price,  F.com_name
   FROM item_mast A INNER JOIN company_mast F
   ON A.pro_com = F.com_id
     AND 
 inner join (SELECT MAX(A.pro_price) max_price,pro_com 
         FROM item_mast A
         group by A.pro_com  ) A2 ON A2.pro_com = A.pro_com and A.pro_price =A2.max_price
```

You can use window function to pickup max prod price.

```
select pro_name,  pro_price,  com_name 
FROM 
(SELECT A.pro_name, A.pro_price, F.com_name,
row_number() over( partition by A.pro_name order by A.pro_name, A.pro_price desc) rn
FROM item_mast A 
INNER JOIN company_mast F  ON A.pro_com = F.com_id) rs
WHERE rs.rn=1
```

EDIT : Explanation : row number is going to give increasing number to the combination of item name and price. So for an item, largest price will be row #1, then next price will be row#2 and so on. So, if we pick row number =1  we will get largest price.

Comment: They were asking what their current code is doing, not how to replace it, especially not with something _else_ that doesn't explain what/how it's doing... You should explain your answer, e.g. what does the code seem to be doing, why it "may not work", and how yours fixes that.

Comment: I changed OP's sql as well to make it work the way OP is intending.